# Empty input box onclick in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I've no idea why this isn't working, but I'm sure it's a very common bit of Javascript. My syntax is clearly lacking, and I don't know why:

```
<input type="text" value="search" id="search" name="q" onclick="javascript:if($(this).val() == 'search') {$(this).val() = '';} return false;" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your issue is with this line of code:

```
$(this).val() = ''
```

The proper way to set a value in jQuery is:

```
$(this).val("Your value here");
```

In addition, inline JS is never a good idea. Use this instead:

```
$("#search").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "search")
        $(this).val("")
});​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/Yu97Z/).

References: [jQuery `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 4):

Put this in a separate js file...

this will return it to the initial value if nothing is typed after it loses focus.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#search").focus( function() {
        if ( $(this).val()=="search") {
            $(this).val('');
        } 
    });

    $("#search").blur( function() {
        if ( $(this).val()=="") {
            $(this).val('search');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: This is also great, I actually wrote the same code after James's answer. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this:

```
<input type="text" value="search" id="search" name="q" onclick="javascript:if($(this).val() == 'search') {$(this).val('');} return false;" />

correct way   : $this.val('');
incorrect way : $this.val() = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).val() = '';
```

should be

```
$(this).val('');
```

See [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This has become easier with a HTML5 Placeholder:

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search query here">
```

It's not supported in older browsers, but if you're only targeting modern ones, you should be fine to use it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: The placeholder attribute does indeed make this much easier (provided your browser supports it), but you should avoid just posting links as answers. Links have a tendency to rot and disappear. The main content should be posted into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

no you need $(this).val(""); or $(this).val(''); to empty it

```
<input type="text" value="search" id="search" name="q" onclick="javascript:if($(this).val() == 'search') {$(this).val('');} return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can clear the input field by using

> `$(this).val('');`

Answer (score -2):

```
function search(textBox)
{
   if($(textBox).val() == 'search') {
        $(textBox).val() = '';
   } 
   return false;
}

<input type="text" value="search" id="search" name="q" onclick="return search();" />
```

Try this and debug.